# Send to the frontend what permissions user have

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app that have React on the frontend and Django on the backend. My problem is that I need to restrict CRUD operations by user permissions. I need to send some information to the frontend

Example when I request something to the backend API to receive something like this:

```
{
  data: [],
  permissions: [
    read: true,
    write: true,
    upload: false,
    delete: false,
  ]
}
```

Can anyone have some idea how to do that? Or is a better way?

Comment: here is good example with jquery: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

Post Calling the api your can store response in state.

Then pass the permission to component

Example-

```
axios.get(/apicall).then((res) => this.setState({
    userPermission: res.permission
}))

render(
   const {userPermission}= this.state

   return <Component 
             read={userPermission.read}
             write={userPermission.write}
             upload={userPermission.upload}
             delete={userPermission.delete} />
  )
```

You can disable button based on props in your Component.

Comment: I know how to do it on the frontend but my problem is in the backend I need to attach the permissions to data

Comment: Have you tried Object.assign({}, {data:[]}, {permissions: [
    read: true,
    write: true,
    upload: false,
    delete: false,
  ]}) to merge the data. Not sure if you looking for this